How to change android app meta data that showed in opened apps view?

Does anyone know what is the pointed text called and how to change that?
It only shows in some Chinese phones.
I have tried searching the text in my source code but I cannot guess which one to change.
It's also different from android:label in AndroidManifest.xml
